# Scraping from encrypted HTML

Tags: html, vb.net, web-scraping

I want to scrape data with vb.net form http://zvartnots.am/new/ however the downloaded code came with some white part which is the actual  table that I need.

```
<th width="93">Факт. время прибытия</th>
                                            </tr>
```

between these tags is the code that i need to auto-scrape

```
</thead>
<tbody id="flight_data">
```

this is the code of the part I need (encrypted) and here is my scrape

```
Protected Function gethtml(ByVal url As String)
    Dim rt As String = ""

    Dim wReq As WebRequest
    Dim wRes As WebResponse

    Dim SReader As StreamReader
    Try
        wReq = WebRequest.Create(url)
        wRes = wReq.GetResponse

        SReader = New StreamReader(wRes.GetResponseStream)

        rt = SReader.ReadToEnd
        SReader.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try


    Return rt
End Function

Protected Sub btnhtml_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnhtml.Click
    htmltxtbox.Text = gethtml(urltxtbox.Text)
End Sub
```

Comment: I have no idea what the problem is nor I want to open the link in your question. Please add [mcve] here on stackoverflow that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I have no idea what this is all about. What exactly is "encrypted HTML"? As already mentioned, needs a MCVE

Comment: you can see view-source:http://zvartnots.am/new/ and the main part of code is invisible (the table part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such a thing as "encrypted" HTML. The problem is that the data from the table you want to scrape is not on the HTML served from the server, but gets generated from Javascript after page load, by making another request to another URL, and processing the response.

If you fire up the inspector and go to the network tab, you can see these extra requests, and the data as it is received by the page Javascript code, which adds it to the table.

[image: Snapshot of inspector]